# Javafx Постоянное отображение обновляемой переменной

Tags: java, javafx, listener

Имеется в fxml есть TextField fx:id="NEWmsg"
в классе Controller находится public static String MSG, которая меняет свои значения от внешних условий, нужно, чтобы в NEWmsg выводилась эта переменная и менялась при каждом её изменении без нажатия кнопок.

Comment: а как меняется MSG? вызывается её сеттер или напрямую?

Comment: MSG меняется в другом классе (Listener X-Bee модуля), но инициализирован он в контроллере. Сейчас стоит кнопка которая запускает метод в контроллере     helloWorld.setText(MSG); а нужно, чтобы Текст выводился сам, каждый раз, когда меняется значение MSG

Comment: а как меняется MSG? вызывается её сеттер или напрямую?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {

    public static final String getMsg() { return MSG.get(); }
    public static final void setMsg(String msg) { MSG.set(msg); }
    public static final StringProperty MSGProperty() { return MSG; }
    private static final StringProperty MSG = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    @FXML private TextField NEWmsg;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Если поле только для отображения (не может изменять значение MSG)
        NEWmsg.textProperty().bind(MSGProperty());
        // Если через это поле можно менять значение MSG
//        NEWmsg.textProperty().bindBidirectional(MSGProperty());
    }
}

public class OtherClass {

    public void updateMyControllerMsg() {
        MyController.setMsg("Random message");
    }

}
```

Comment: public static final String getMsg() { return MSG.get(); }
    public static final void setMsg(String msg) { MSG.set(msg); } - не совсем понял зачем нужны эти строки, тем более, что MSG.get и MSG.set вообще не распознаются
    
    public static final StringProperty MSGProperty() { return MSG; } - тоже отказывается так делить из-за некорректного типа (требует StringProperty вместо String)
    даже есть создать нулевой MSG типа StringProperty после добавления  NEWmsg.textProperty().bind(MSGProperty()); начинает сыпать исключениями и ничего не запускается.

Comment: данная схема должна быть рабочей, скорее всего вы ее не так используете (как описывали в посте). Методы `getMsg`, `setMsg` и `MSGProperty` - так принято описывать api к полям `property`. "Тоже отказывается делить" - что значит делить? "создать нулевой MSG" - не надо, должно быть так, как есть. Исключения - покажите код (который можно запустить и увидеть исключения) что бы можно было помочь более конкретно.

Answer (score 0):

Увы, не найдя рецепта, пришлось впихивать класс лисенера прямо в контроллер, такми образом setText отрабатывается при каждой отработке лисенера.